# What is the "good way" to subscribe to value changes in a JFormattedTextField?

Tags: java, swing, events, jformattedtextfield

I want to subscribe to value changes on a JFormattedTextField.

Checking the source code, the only thing I see is that the property "value" is fired on a new value. But this property is only referenced there, and directly written, without a constant. If I subscribe to this property change, it works.

However, I'm wondering: is this the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[JavaDoc for JFormattedTextField](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) states[:

> Once a JFormattedTextField has been
>   created, you can listen for editing
>   changes by way of adding a
>   PropertyChangeListener and listening
>   for PropertyChangeEvents with the
>   property name value.

That means that you are using the correct way

Comment: Indeed, I missed this line in the javadoc. Thank you.